# Delphi 2006 - Creating locale-independent exponential-formatted numbers

Tags: delphi, formatting, scientific-notation

I use the older functions `Str` and `Val` to write and read values that need to be persistent across different locales, but can you instruct `Str` to always format a floating point number in scientific format?

I.e I want all floating point numbers to be formatted this way and fit inside 16 characters:

`-1.234567890E-34`

(2 digits is sufficient for the exponent). This maximizes precision and dynamic range for a given storage size.

Comment: The *correct* way to deal with locale independence is to use RTL parsing/formatting functions that accept `TFormatSettings` (introduced in Delphi 7) as input, such as `Format()` and `StrToFloat()` .Then you can specify your own consistent formats that are not affected by external locales.

Comment: Thanks @Remy.  I was looking to extending the existing routine that uses `Str`,  but if there is no way to do that I will use the `TFormatSettings`  approach.

Comment: You cannot change how `Str()` formats its output. You can tell it the desired number of decimal places for floating-point numbers, but that is all you can do. `Format()` and `FloatToStr()` are more flexible.